# Java mirror image diagonal method not working

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting my method to work. The method should mirror any image I choose on its diagonal to produce a mirror effect, but at the moment it just produces the same image unedited and I don't what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
public Picture mirrorImageDiagonal() {
  int size = this.getWidth();
  Pixel rightPixel = null;
  Pixel leftTargetPixel = null;
  Pixel rightTargetPixel = null;
  Picture target = new Picture(size, size);
  for (double x = 0; x < size; x ++) {
      for (double y = 0; y <= x; y ++) {
          int yIndex = Math.min((int) y, this.getHeight() - 1);
          int xIndex = Math.min((int) x, this.getWidth() - 1);
          leftTargetPixel = target.getPixel(yIndex, xIndex);
          rightTargetPixel = target.getPixel(xIndex, yIndex);
          rightPixel = this.getPixel(xIndex, yIndex);
          rightTargetPixel.setColor(rightPixel.getColor());
          leftTargetPixel.setColor(rightPixel.getColor());
          }
    }
  return target;
  }
```

Comment: leftTargetPixel.setColor( letPixel.getColor());

Comment: Where id you get Picture.java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you are trying to complete the challenge for A6 in the picture lab packet. I just completed this for school, but if you are not, I hope this still helps you.

```
public void mirrorDiagonal()
  {
    Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();
    Pixel pixel1 = null;
    Pixel pixel2 = null;
    int width = pixels[0].length;
    for (int row = 0; row < pixels.length; row++)
    {
      for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
      {
        if (col < pixels.length)
        {
            pixel1 = pixels[row][col];
            pixel2 = pixels[col][row];
            pixel1.setColor(pixel2.getColor());
        }
      }
    } 
  }
```